# WP 3.8 theme customizer error

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to make some customizer for my theme, but i've got JS error "Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined " LOL. I wrote all code based on Codex, maybe it is just WP 3.8 bug? Or what i'm doing wrong?

my code - PHP:

```
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'customizer_preview' );

function customizer_preview() {
        wp_register_script( 'wproto-customizer-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin/screen-customizer.js', '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wproto-customizer-preview', array( 'jquery', 'customize-preview' ) );
}
```

JS:

```
( function( $ ) {

    // here i've got an error "wp is not defined"
    wp.customize( 'blogname', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            $( '#text-logo .site-title' ).html( newval );
        } );
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way of enqueueing is wrong here. When you use [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), you only need to pass the handle to [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Try updating your function to:

```
function customizer_preview() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wproto-customizer-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin/screen-customizer.js', array( 'jquery', 'customize-preview' ) );
}
```

Comment: Who would have thought that the error at this! Thank you RRikesh, you are the Master :)